# How to write IF condition in column of Web grid

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, webgrid

i have get error the create the if condition in to column of WEB GRID so...please help to improve my code and solved to my prob....

```
grid.Column("Status", format: item => 
@<text>
@if (item.Is_active = true)
{ 
    @<a href="Url.Action("UserStatus", "Admin")"><img src="../../images/Active.png"/></a> 
} else
{ 
    @<a href="Url.Action("UserStatus", "Admin")"><img src="../../images/Deactive.png"/></a> 
}
</text>),
```

Comment: best overloaded method metch for system.web.helpers.webgrid.column(string,string,system.func<dynamic,object>,string , bool) has some invalid argument..!

Comment: There is at least one syntax error there: the "= true" in the if statement needs to be "== true" (double-equals sign). Is that the actual bug here or do you get an error even with that?

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
grid.Column(
    "Status", 
    format: 
        @<a href="@Url.Action("UserStatus", "Admin")">
            <img src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/images/{0}.png", item.Is_active ? "Active" : "Deactive"))" alt="" />
        </a>
)
```

Notice how I have fixed the `src` of your image because you have hardcoded it instead of using an url helper which you should never do.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
grid.Column("Status", format: item => 
        (bool)item.Is_active ?
        <a href="Url.Action("UserStatus", "Admin")"><img src="../../images/Active.png"/></a> :
        <a href="Url.Action("UserStatus", "Admin")"><img src="../../images/Deactive.png"/></a>)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{ WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model.LstContactUsers, selectionFieldName: "SelectedRow", canPage: false); @grid.GetHtml(tableStyle: "grid_rt", headerStyle: "background:none;height:0px;display:none", displayHeader: false, alternatingRowStyle: "grid-row-style", rowStyle: "grid-row-style", columns: grid.Columns( grid.Column(" ", header: null, style: "grid-row-style", format: @ @item.FName  @item.LName 
***@if( @item.Email.Contains("Group")) { @item.Email } else { 
@item.Email }*** )))
}
```