# If condition in webgrid

Tags: webgrid

I want to show the image if the item has image, and no image otherwise. Here is my code, but it gets some errors.

So how to use if condition in format parameter of webgrid?

```
grid.Column("Image", "Ảnh minh họa", format: (item) =>
        if(item.Image == null)
        {
            @<text>Chưa có ảnh minh họa</text>
        }
        else
        {
            @<text><img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Content("~/images/")@item.Image" /></text>
        }
        , canSort: false)
```

**Edit:**
I have solved this issue. Here is my code:

```
grid.Column("Image", "Ảnh minh họa", format: @<text>@if (item.Image == null) { <text>Chưa có ảnh minh họa</text> } else { <text><img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Content("~/images/")@item.Image" /></text> }</text>
                    , canSort: false),
```

Comment: Does your item.Image contains relative path to the image file?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
grid.Column("Image", "Ảnh minh họa", format: (item) =>
        if((string)item.Image == null)
        {
            @<text>Chưa có ảnh minh họa</text>
        }
        else
        {
            @<text><img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/images/{0}",(string)item.Image))" /></text>
        }
        , canSort: false)
```

---

**Edit**

```
grid.Column("Image", "Ảnh minh họa",
   format: item.Image == null 
   ? @<text>Chưa có ảnh minh họa</text> : @<text><img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Content(string.Format("~/images/{0}",(string)item.Image))" /></text>, 
   canSort: true)
```

Comment: Hi Karthik, I try as you show but still get error:

The name 'item' does not exist in the current context

The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: I get this error:

**The name 'item' does not exist in the current context**

and

**The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.Helpers.WebGrid.Column(string, string, System.Func<dynamic,object>, string, bool)' has some invalid arguments**

Comment: I try with the new code you've edited but get the same error.

and new error:
**Argument 3: cannot convert from 'lambda expression' to 'System.Func<dynamic,object>**

Comment: what is the type of Image ? is it string type. I mean does it show the path to the file

Comment: Yes, item.Image is a string. Can you give me a sample code with condition (if, else) in format parameter, similar my code above?

Comment: Please check this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14972848/how-to-write-if-condition-in-column-of-web-grid/14974251#14974251)

Comment: Thank you Karthik,

Finally, I have solved this issue. Here is my code:

    grid.Column("Image", "Ảnh minh họa", format: @<text>@if (item.Image == null) { <text>Chưa có ảnh minh họa</text> } else { <text><img width="50" height="50" src="@Url.Content("~/images/")@item.Image" /></text> }</text>
                        , canSort: false),